# Embaralhar lista em c++

Tags: c++, lista-encadeada

Quero saber como eu posso, dada uma lista, embaralhar a ordem dos elementos que nela estão. O tipo estrutura da lista que quero embaralhar é a seguinte.

```
struct exemplo {
  int I;
  int O;
  int V;
  struct exemplo *prox;
}
```

Comment: Não entendi sua questão. Está muito aberta e pouco clara. Como é sua estrutura? Seu nó da lista contém um objeto e o ponteiro para o próximo nó? Ou um  vetor e um ponteiro para o próximo nó? É simplesmente encadeada?

Comment: Na estrutura eu tenho 3 valores inteiros, e o ponteiro para o próximo nó.

Comment: Aí os exemplos que eu conseguir achar as estruturas tinham 1 valor só na estrutura, ai passavam para o vetor e embaralhavam e retornavam os valores pra lista

Comment: [edit] sua pergunta insira as informações relevantes

Comment: Ok, vou editar a pergunta

Comment: Não está querendo dizer que é para criar uma função que pega uma lista e, ao terminar a execução da função, a ordem dos elementos está sorteada? É isso que é embaralhar os elementos, seriam os elementos que já estão dentro da lista?

Comment: Isso, eu ja tenho uma lista, aí eu quero embaralhar os elementos. Aí o nó da lista vai conter esses elementos

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente usar a funçao rand() que gera um numero de 1 a 3, depois com esses numeros trocas os elementos que tem nessa lista de ordem aleatoria